# Setup Synergy without IP addresses

Tags: synergy

I have a Windows XP and Mac and would like to share my keyboard and mouse. I can setup Synergy using the IP addresses of the two machines, however when I restart any of the machines the IP addresses change, which means I have to configure it again. Is it possible to set up Synergy for using only the computer names of the machines?

Answer (score 0):

Without setting up DNS, this is not possible. And setting up DNS is more complex than two other options you have:

1. If your router supports it, assign static IPs to your two machines.  This requires no change on your Windows and Mac machines, it just means that your router will always give the same IP to each machine.
2. If your router does not support assigning static IPs, then you can do it manually on each machine.  First, try to determine the address range your router uses when assigning dynamic IPs (192.168.1.100-192.168.1.150, for instance), then assign static IPs *outside* that range (so there's no possibility of conflict when you plug another machine into your network).  For instance, 192.168.1.99 and 192.168.1.98, in this example.

Either of these will allow you to use IP addresses, since they won't change.

Answer (score 0):

On your server machine you can set up "aliases" in newer versions of Synergy for the client screens, but that doesn't help with the client trying to resolve the server.

As the other answer suggested, using static IPs is the easiest route, otherwise if you have a decent router with advanced options you can usually enable the setting to resolve hostnames so you can ping your computers by name. If you don't have a router that is that smart, you can try using something like dnsmasq running on a Linux VM to keep track of the hostname<>IP mappings.

Absolute worst case (may introduce some latency) if you have Synergy Pro with the SSL encryption option (huge security risk if you don't) you can open a port in your firewall (don't use the standard Synergy port) and then forward that to your server and use any of the dynamic DNS providers (dyndns.org/noip.com/etc) to register a static DNS name and then your router or your server machine can run an update client to up your "hostname" with your external IP and the port forward will allow your clients to reach through and talk to the server.

Idea taken from https://symless.com/forums/topic/1926-how-to-use-synergy-between-local-lan-and-vpn-connected-pcs/